# Convert past date format in php

Tags: php

I'm upload the excel data into mysql. in there date save like 16.5.59(dd.mm.yy) formate. I try to change this using this code

```
$date = '16.5.59'; 
echo date('d-m-y',strtotime($date));
```

it always show current time like 04-02-15.
Pls change this to dd-mm-yyyy formate.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post your code so far please?

Comment: $date = '16.5.59'; echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));

Comment: u want it in 59.5.16 format?

Comment: 16.5.59 is in dd-mm-yyyy format already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$date = '16.5.59';
$date_array = explode(".",$date);
$var_day = $date_array[0];
$var_month = $date_array[1];

> Blockquote

$var_year = $date_array[2];
echo $new_date_format = "$var_day-$var_month-$var_year";
```

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

If it not cover the between given range then it will take current date.

Comment: My answer works, but it seems that the date was still before 01-01-1970. I tried using online PHP code grounds to test the code, and if the `$date` was   `1.1.1980` it works and `1.1.1970` does not.

Comment: ok thaks for imporve my knowledge. but i need to make date format . my task is convert offline data to online the list start from 1939. :/

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the date yourself using `explode` and `strtotime`:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$date = '16.5.59';

$date_time = strtotime(implode('-', array_reverse(explode('.', $date))))
$date_str = date('d-m-Y', $date_time);

echo $date_str;
```

Output: `16-5-2059`

You **ARE** required to specify that the year is `1959` instead of `2059` (or are you sure that it's really 2059?)

You can make change from `2059` to `1959` like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$date = '16.5.59';

$date_arr = array_reverse(explode('.', $date))

# This line does the job. Make sure all years are between 1900 - 1999.
$date_arr[0] = '19' . $date_arr[0];

$date_time = strtotime(implode('-', $date_arr))
$date_str = date('d-m-Y', $date_time);

echo $date_str;
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: can we find the year 1900 - 1999 and 2000 to 2015 or put the condition on it.

Comment: yes! just check the length of the string (`$date_arr[0]`). If it's `length == 4` then you may not need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the best solution but using php's `date_parse_from_format` is possible. You could supply a format and use the following

```
$date = "16.5.59";
$dateObj = date_parse_from_format("j.n.yy", $date)
```

with the `$dateObj` you can work what you need such as :

```
 echo $dateObj['year'];
```

[IDE Running Example](https://ideone.com/maPWLj)

Worth noting you require `PHP >=v5.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if it is for simpler task. It will consume time.

```
$date = '16.5.59'; 
$dtSplit=explode(".",$date);
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[0].".".$dtSplit[1].".".$dtSplit[2];
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[0].".".$dtSplit[2].".".$dtSplit[1];
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[1].".".$dtSplit[0].".".$dtSplit[2];
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[1].".".$dtSplit[2].".".$dtSplit[0];
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[2].".".$dtSplit[0].".".$dtSplit[1];
echo "<br>".$dtSplit[2].".".$dtSplit[1].".".$dtSplit[0];
```

Comment: I just wrote all the combination